# Correct way to add java file and its dependencies into my project in android studio

Tags: java, android, structure

I tried adding .jar files into my android project as a dependency but it didnt work, so now im trying to add just the java files I need. 
Lets call the file I want cookies.java, and then within the original package structure there is a util folder with 2 files cookies.java needs to execute lets call them cookieDough and cookieRecipe and the pacakage is located int net.sourceforge.cooking.
So it it would end up being 3 files I need:

```
net.sourceforge.cooking.cookies.java
net.sourceforge.cooking.util.cookieDough.java
net.sourceforge.cooking.util.cookieRecipe.java
```

what I am trying to do is add a cooking folder with the cookies.java class
and inside the cooking folder a util folder with the cookieDough and cookieRecipe classes. so:

```
cooking/cookies.java
cooking/util/cookieDough.java
cooking/util/cookieRecipe.java
```

My main program is under

```
src/main/java/packagename/
```

I tried 
creating a java folder withing src, `src/cooking` but im having trouble getting both the cookies.java to find the `/util/cookieDough.java` and also for my classes withing `src/main/java/packagename/` to find the cookies.java or the other files.

The files im adding already have package and import declarations but since im making them local I know I have to change these, I dont know if I need them to be a package all together.

Questions:

1- where is the right location to add the cooking folder within my project structure.

2- how do I get the files im adding to recognize each other, meaning how do i get cookies.java to find `util/cookieRecipe.java`?, do I have to declare them as a package

3- How do I get my java classes in `src/main/java/packagename/` to find the classes in the cooking directory, an import statement??

It all works if I  just add the 3 java files into my main package and remove all import and package statements from them, but I would like to figure out how to do it the right way (best practices) and i am assuming I should have those files separate from mine.

BTW the files I'm adding are opensource.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried adding .jar files into my android project as a dependency but it didnt work

What happened led you to know that it "didn't work"? This can be a more important question leave to be solved, and may be the "best practise" you mentioned in the end of your question.

But for the other question about putting that `.java` file directly, the original question seems a little mess. You just remember to put every `.java` file in the directory indicated by that file's `package` statement relative to `src/main/java`.

Take your question as an example, you seems to add `net.sourceforge.cooking.cookies.java` (which means, a file under directory `net/sourceforge/cooking`, names `cookies.java`, with a `package net.sourceforge.cooking;` statement inside it), then you can create a package **under `src/main/java`** to put that file, which indicates that your file can be `src/main/java/net/sourceforge/cooking/cookies.java`. (Yes, this directory ignores the original directory of your main source in `src/main/java/packagename`.) Hope this is an answer to question 1.

For question 2, what you need seems just an `import` statement,

```
import net.sourceforge.cooking.util.cookieRecipe
```

in what directory it stays will indicate what package name it has. So you have to declare the package name, but just a `package` statement in Java as common, no need for other declarations, no other configurations.

And question 3 is the same, you don't need to care that you are dealing with two package trees with no common package, one is `net.sourceforge.cooking`, and the other is `packagename`, (or in directory, one is `src/main/java/net/sourceforge/cooking`, the other is `src/main/java/packagename`)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the great answer, the reason why adding the package didnt work I made a post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47514818/dex-error-when-i-include-jar-files-into-my-android-project

Comment: About question 1 
I wanted to cut out the begining (net.sourceforge) in my project and just start it from the cooking folder, I was able to do it like this using the method you described, I dont know if it is ok to cut it out or if it is more proper to leave it with its original path(best practices question), I just felt it would make it clearer not to have the net.sourceforge which doesnt have any files.

Comment: Also I dont know if I should open a new post about this but, when I add the cooking folder and util folder that goes within it I do it via new->package but I wasnt sure if to use the new->folder->java folder, but then I get a configure component window with a change folder location check box and I dont really understand what its asking. Did I do it the right way? what is the java folder option for? Thanks!

Comment: @Jack If you want to cut out the beginning, you just simply remove that beginning of the `package` statement of every file you mentioned, then move those file to the new folder (for example, a file `src/main/java/cooking/cookies.java`, with its `package` statement `package cooking`).

Comment: Yeah I did just that worked great, was just wondering if it was best practice to leave the full path or if it doesnt really matter :D, thanks for the help!