# Unable to merge dex in android studio

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Comment: What is your question? Just posting the beginning of an error message makes is very hard to help you. Please provide some details around this (what you try when the error occurrs, your gradle.file, ...). Also a good read is https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your demand is not very precise...
Have you try this ?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47187787/10159898

Answer (score 0):

add this line in gradle.property

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m
```

Comment: Please explain your solution further.

Comment: when I got a dex related error I change in gradle. property and inside build. gradle multiDexEnabled true

Comment: android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}